# When i click edit button all my table value changed to input box?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

My HTML contains ng for and I have taken index value and using index value I can take my values into the input box.But all my table list shows same value and input box open.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">
  <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
  <td>
    <!-- {{ item.itemName }} -->
    <span *ngIf="!myvar">{{ item.itemName }}</span>
    <span *ngIf="myvar"><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="editUpdate.itemName" name="update.name" (keyup.enter)="UpdateItem()" (keyup.escape)="cancelEditingTodo()"></span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <!-- {{ item.itemType }} -->
    <span *ngIf="!myvar">{{ item.itemType }}</span>
    <span *ngIf="myvar"><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="editUpdate.itemType" name="update.name" (keyup.enter)="UpdateItem()" (keyup.escape)="cancelEditingTodo()"></span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <!-- {{ item.itemDescription }} -->
    <span *ngIf="!myvar">{{ item.itemDescription }}</span>
    <span *ngIf="myvar"><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="editUpdate.itemDescription" name="update.name" (keyup.enter)="UpdateItem()" (keyup.escape)="cancelEditingTodo()"></span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <!-- {{ item.itemCurrentPrice }} -->
    <span *ngIf="!myvar">{{ item.itemCurrentPrice }}</span>
    <span *ngIf="myvar"><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="editUpdate.itemCurrentPrice" name="update.name" (keyup.enter)="UpdateItem()" (keyup.escape)="cancelEditingTodo()"></span>
  </td>
  <td><i class="fa fa-pencil" (click)="editItem(i)" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
  <td><i class="fa fa-trash" (click)="deleteItem(i)" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
</tr>
```

My ts file is

```
editItem(i: number) {
  this.myvar=true;
  this.index=i;
  this.editUpdate=this.items[this.index];
  console.log("edit", this.editUpdate);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `*ngIf=` expressions to

```
 *ngIf="i !== index"
 *ngIf="i === index"
```

Comment: Just replace `!myvar` and `myvar` by `i !== index` and `i === index`

Comment: It Works fine But my database file did not receive from ts.Error occurs as cannot read property ref as undefined

Comment: @ Günter Zöchbauer   Can you send alternate for this please

Comment: Alternative for what?

Comment: Sorry i get it . I want to null the index value thanks bro.